# Iterators for Unordered Map

Tags: c++, iterator

I was wondering how I would go about creating my own iterators for an unordered map. My map uses vectors where each bucket is a linked list. Using this design however, I am not sure how I would iterate the linked lists and then iterate from bucket to bucket. I don't necessarily want the code, but rather the concept behind what to do.

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: With no code posted It is not obvious what prevents you from iterating from last element of list of current bucket to first element of list of next nonempty bucket.

Comment: I don’t understand the downvotes or the comments. OP is clearly asking for how to go about doing this — providing code is not something he knows how to do, and playing with iterators is something that regularly confuses people who have been using C++ for more than a while.

Answer (score 2):

An ***iterator*** is really just something that *looks* like a pointer, but it doesn’t actually have to be anything like a pointer at all. It can be a complete class.

In your case, you need two iterators: one for the buckets, and one for the elements of each bucket. Wrap that in a class:

```
struct my_unordered_map_iterator
{
  my_bucket_iterator bucket_iter;
  my_vector_iterator element_iter;
};
```

Each time you increment the `element_iter`, check it against `bucket_iter->end()`. If you have reached the end of the bucket then increment the `bucket_iter` and reset the `element_iter` the the first element of the new bucket.

Creating the iterators then requires you only to populate things properly:

- `begin()` ⟶ `{ bucket_begin(), bucket_begin()->elements.begin() }`
- `end()` ⟶ `{ bucket_end(), nullptr }`

Of course you must also override all the necessary operators for your iterator class to make the iterators work: `*`, `->`, `++`, `==`, `!=`, etc. How many of these operators you implement depend on your iterator class. I suggest you consider a bidirectional iterator at minimum, which you can implement via a forward iterator and a `std::reverse_iterator`.